# iPhone Email - How to prevent a datestamp from being turned into a Link to Create an Event

Tags: iphone, email, ios

I have an email that has something like:

XXXX 4:20pm Feb 11 assdaasddsadsa
XXXX 4:20pm Feb 11 assdaasddsadsa
XXXX 4:20pm Feb 11 assdaasddsadsa

The iPhone keeps turning 4:20pm Feb 11 into a link to create an event on the iPhone which looks real ugly, dark blue link.

Is there a way to prevent this, and tell iOS to ignore this in the Mail App?

Thanks

Comment: Anyway to have a date stamp with iphone?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience no,

Apple is just trying to make your life and the recipients lives easier by using microformats, an in this case the hCalendar version so that they can be understood by other programs {like a calendar app}.

see:

http://microformats.org/wiki/hcalendar for a full explanation of the format.

The only way-tat i know of-to solve this would be to jailbreak your iphone and change the style of the formatting [or remove the format altogether].

There is an issue with microformats that you may want to consider if you email blind people, see:

http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/bbcinternet/2008/06/removing_microformats.html

I know that this does not explicitly tell you how to sort this yourself, but I hope that with this knowledge you may just overlook the bad style in favour of the time savings that the hCalendar offers you and others.